# SEM model using counts in lavaan

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, count-data

I am trying to use SEM for an analysis, but the measured variable to which everything else in my data-set is correlated is an integer. I am not sure if this is the culprit, but I am receiving issues related to non-convergence.

I cannot find much in terms of how to deal with measured variables that are integers, other than some suggest converting them to ordinal variables, and using a generalized SEM.  This won't work in my situation, though, because the latent variable is then multiplied with other measured variables, so as to identify additional latent variables.

Suggestions??

Comment: Can you specify your setup more clearly, perhaps load a figure of your path diagram? That may be your problem, not the counts.

Comment: I dug around the laavan support group, and found that counts are not supported, but to give the estimator="mlr" command a try.  I have other issues to fix, but if it's still throwing errors, I'll post the diagram.

Comment: mlr won't help - it's still maximum likelihood.

Comment: It was suggested in the laavan google group by the developer.  However, the data are going to need  analyzed using either a Zero Inflated Negative Binomial model or a ZIP model.  Mplus has ZIP, but any ideas for the other??  Also, the data fit the NB distribution better than Poisson, but in the end, how much will that matter???